# how to implement tab functionality in an app?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement tab functionality without using `js` .I got the example from here

https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/tab_panels_with_amp-selector/

I am able to use this example when I have only `two` tabs.
see output
https://jsbin.com/vixaquloki/edit?html,output

But when I tried to make nested tab  "**tabs inside a another tabs" .**.It show nothing .why ?
see my code

but when I click `tab one` it show both inside `tabs` ..but when I click **"inside Tab one"** it hide every thing why ?

```
<amp-selector role="tablist"
              layout="container1"
              class="ampTabContainer">
    <div role="tab"
         class="tabButton"
         selected
         option="a">Tab one</div>
    <div role="tabpanel"
         class="tabContent">
```

Comment: Why do you tag js if youre saying *without js* ???

Comment: it use `scripts ` that why

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that selected command is being conflict see this
i just **deleted the selected** command from inner tab

```
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp-custom>
        .ampTabContainer {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .tabButton[selected] {
            outline: none;
            background: #ccc;
        }

        .tabButton {
            list-style: none;
            flex-grow: 1;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .tabContent {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            order: 1; /* must be greater than the order of the tab buttons to flex to the next line */
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .tabButton[selected]+.tabContent {
            display: block;
        }

        /* For example below (not required) */
        .itemCustom {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            height: 280px;
            width: 380px;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 140px;
        }
        amp-selector {
            padding: 1rem;
            margin: 1rem;
        }
    </style>

<amp-selector role="tablist" layout="container1" class="ampTabContainer">
    <div role="tab" class="tabButton" selected option="a">Tab one</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">

      <div>one div 
      <amp-selector role="tablist" layout="container" class="ampTabContainer">
  <div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="a">inside Tab one</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">Tab one content... </div>
  <div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="b">Tab two</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">Tab two content... </div> </amp-selector> </div> </div>
    <div role="tab"
         class="tabButton"
         option="b">Tab two</div>
    <div role="tabpanel"
         class="tabContent">Tab two content... </div>

</amp-selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `selected` from:

```
<div role="tab"
    class="tabButton"
    selected
    option="a">inside Tab one</div>
```

**Update**

I think you want to show both content of tab one and inside tab one.
To allow multiple selections add multiple attribute to `amp-selector` element.

[Here's an updated jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wawesanuve/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: share fddle or jsbin link

Comment: Check out my update. Let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Nevermind. I just realized that doesn't work properly.

Comment: so it mean we can't use nested amp=elector

Comment: I don't think you can unless you use javascript and simulate a click event on the inner tab.